# How to calculate this shape sides?

Tags: geometry

I have the following geometric shape.

[image]

How can I calculate a, b and c?

Comment: You should try to solve it  yourself, show part of that and ask question when you could not proceed further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: figure with extra notations]

I have marked $2$ extra lines on the figure, which form a right angle with $x$. I have also split $a$ into $a_1$ and $a_2$.

The triangle with the yellow line as one of its sides is a right triangle. The yellow line has the same length as $d_1$. Then, we have $\tan(\alpha)=\frac{d_1}{a_1}$, from which its easy to get $a_1$. $a_2$ is equal to $x$, since they are part of a rectangle, so $a=a_1+x$. By Pythagora in the same triangle, we get the length of $c_1$.

The orange line is equal in length to $d_2$. Then in the right triangle we get $\sin(\beta)=\frac{d_2}{c_2}$, from which you can obtain $c_2$, and finally $c$ as $c_1+c_2$.

Finally, we have $\tan(\beta)=\frac{d_2}{x_1}$, and $b=x-x_1$.

I'm sure you can work out the computations!

Comment: Try not to answer questions when someone dumps one here, like the above, with no effort. Apart from being against [site policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/10513), it is more helpful to get them to do some work themselves (which is why people often ask "what have you tried?"). Also, it is not unlikely that this is their [assessed homework or exam](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33557/10513), so giving them the complete answer is unfair to the rest of their class.